# Angular - Dynamic Route right after Domain e.g. example.com/:id?

Tags: angular

I want to get the User-ID right after the Domain e.g. example.com/user1 (example.com/:id) and not something like example.com/user/user1 (example.com/user/:id). How is that possible? Below is my Routing Module. I want to drop all these page paths and put there just :id instead. So that it is dynamically. Page means just "User" in our code.

I would be very happy about the simplest solution.

Kind regards,
Thomas

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  {
    path: '', component: MainComponent, children:
      [
        { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
        { path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent },
        {
          path: 'page',
          component: TabsComponent,
          children: [
            { path: 'photos', component: PhotoListComponent },
            { path: 'videos', component: VideoListComponent }
          ]
        },
        { path: 'page/photos/:id', component: PhotoDetailComponent },
        { path: 'page/videos/:id', component: VideoDetailComponent },
      ]
  },
  { path: 'page/add/photo', component: PhotoAddComponent},
  { path: 'page/add/video', component: VideoAddComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working demo for dynamic routes starting right after domain name and without any prefix routes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-route-test

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution, but the Dev Server shows nothing. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: If I click on your Stackblitz example, the Dev Server starts but shows nothing. Nevertheless, I think that is not important for your solution. So thanks for your help :).

Comment: Would you mind upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem?